# spring-integration Aggregator annontation attributes

Tags: spring-integration

Using spring-integration 4.1.4.
I would like to move my project from xml config to java config.
I'm would like to use @Aggregator annontation, buth I see that attributes are missing (group-timeout, send-partial-result-on-expiry, expire-groups-upon-completion, ...).
How can implement the (missing) attributes from @Aggregator in java (no DSL)?

Answer (score 0):

Those attributes are not currently available on the annotation; please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Currently, the only option for comprehensive java configuration of an aggregator is the Java DSL.